# Degrafa Best Practices

Tags: apache-flex, skinning, degrafa

I've been learning Degrafa recently, and I have noticed that there is not much consistency amongst examples posted on the web.  Is there a place where I can find degrafa best practices (esp. for skinning)? or can anyone suggest examples that use best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer, just a comment, I'm afraid :)

I think one of the challenges is that we (the Degrafa team) continue to develop Degrafa and therefore continue to introduce new (and easier) ways to do things - so some of the older samples are out of date and need to be refreshed. We will be refreshing a number of the older samples on the Degrafa site soon.

We'd love it if the user community starting making more examples as well - I know some people have and that there are a number of discrete examples and tutorials around but it takes a bit of googlehunting to find them and there is not a definitive guide somewhere. I can let you know that at least a couple of people (Jason Hawryluk and Josh McDonald) are working on full theme style skinning examples that will be able to be used as skinning templates to guide people for their own skinning, so this type of thing will be available in time - but I can't say when.

I realise that's not particularly helpful, but if you have specific questions about particular approaches to doing something then please consider posting the questions on the degrafa google group (in addition to posting here as well if you want) as it may get more visibility from current degrafa users, and it will be easier for us to incorporate the solution into a future sample/tutorial, or a collection of best practices.

-Degrafa

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am looking forward to those themed examples, I think it will really help the community

Comment: Not much I can add to Greg's reply, but my work in progress skin is available here: http://code.google.com/p/tickertape/ We're floating around the toobs if you've any specific questions, or queries about skinning a particular component.